# How to load WFS in android ? or whitch engine provides loading WFS in android?

Tags: android, dictionary, gis, osmdroid, wms

I have to use and load wfs and wms in my application
but all android libraries support wms but, not wfs.

Can anyone help me?

Did anyone use an engine to do this?

Comment: To your question of whether somebody has done this before, did you look at [QGIS for android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.qgis.qgis&hl=en_US), certainly QGIS desktop handles WFS and QGIS is open source, so you may find your answer there

Comment: Also see https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/207501/working-with-geoserver-and-openlayers-in-android/207503

Answer (score 1):

The Question is not totally Elaborated, Might need more information on what error or errors you are facing.

I am hoping you could elaborate your situation more and with some images.
OR

You can try these link for **Troubleshooting** with the GeoServer.
http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/production/troubleshooting.html

**WFS reference**

http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/services/wfs/reference.html

Comment: Thank you, but I'm just looking for an engine to do this.

Comment: can geoserver do this in android ?